# Why some method doesn't work after embedding custom manifest file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mono

I try to embed custom manifest file to vb.net source code in order to get Administrator level.

But `Console.WriteLine` method does not work after embedding the manifest file.

Target source file and manifest file is as below.

```vb
' test.vb
Module Test
  Sub Main
    Console.WriteLine("Hello")
  End Sub
End Module
```

```xml
<!--manifest.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I compile this files using Mono compiler on Windows 10.

```
vbc /win32manifest:manifest.xml test.vb
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work with Mono compiler.
The manifest file is the only option that will set permission to the administrator for your .exe.

This can be done using .Net framework with Visual Studio.

Comment: is visual studio a verb now?